# VC++ - SQL Update Error [No value given for one or more required parameters.]

Tags: sql, ms-access, visual-c++

I'm using VC++ (Visual C++), and when I update the data, it shows an error message (**Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.**)

This is my sql command text

```
                 "UPDATE students SET "
                 + "[fname] = '" + fname + "', "
                 + "[lname] = '" + lname + "', "
                 + "[mname] = '" + mname + "', "
                 + "[gender] = '" + sex + "', "
                 + "[status] = '" + status + "', "
                 + "[m] = '" + m + "', "
                 + "[d] = '" + d + "', "
                 + "[y] = '" + y + "', "
                 + "[course] = '" + course + "', "
                 + "[shift] = '" + shift + "', "
                 + "[section] = '" + section + "', "
                 + "[homeadd] = '" + homeAdd + "', "
                 + "[proveadd] = '" + provAdd + "', "
                 + "[contactnum] = '" + contactnum + "', "
                 + "[nameguard] = '" + nameGuardian + "', "
                 + "[addguard] = '" + addGuardian + "', "
                 + "[numguard] = '" + numGuardian + "', "
                 + "[sec1] = '" + se1 + "', "
                 + "[sub1] = '" + sub1 + "', "
                 + "[unit1] = '" + unit1 + "', "
                 + "[room1] = '" + room1 + "', "
                 + "[guro1] = '" + guro1 + "', "     
                 + "[sec2] = '" + se2 + "', "
                 + "[sub2] = '" + sub2 + "', "
                 + "[unit2] = '" + unit2 + "', "
                 + "[room2] = '" + room2 + "', "
                 + "[guro2] = '" + guro2 + "', "
                 + "[sec3] = '" + se3 + "', "
                 + "[sub3] = '" + sub3 + "', "
                 + "[unit3] = '" + unit3 + "', "
                 + "[room3] = '" + room3 + "', "
                 + "[guro3] = '" + guro3 + "', "
                 + "[sec4] = '" + se4 + "', "
                 + "[sub4] = '" + sub4 + "', "
                 + "[unit4] = '" + unit4 + "', "
                 + "[room4] = '" + room4 + "', "
                 + "[guro4] = '" + guro4 + "', "
                 + "[sec5] = '" + se5 + "', "
                 + "[sub5] = '" + sub5 + "', "
                 + "[unit5] = '" + unit5 + "', "
                 + "[room5] = '" + room5 + "', "
                 + "[guro5] = '" + guro5 + "', "
                 + "[sec6] = '" + se6 + "', "
                 + "[sub6] = '" + sub6 + "', "
                 + "[unit6] = '" + unit6 + "', "
                 + "[room6] = '" + room6 + "', "
                 + "[guro6] = '" + guro6 + "', "
                 + "[sec7] = '" + se7 + "', "
                 + "[sub7] = '" + sub7 + "', "
                 + "[unit7] = '" + unit7 + "', "
                 + "[room7] = '" + room7 + "', "
                 + "[guro7] = '" + guro7 + "', "
                 + "[sec8] = '" + se8 + "', "
                 + "[sub8] = '" + sub8 + "', "
                 + "[unit8] = '" + unit8 + "', "
                 + "[room8] = '" + room8 + "', "
                 + "[guro8] = '" + guro8 + "', "
                 + "[sec9] = '" + se9 + "', "
                 + "[sub9] = '" + sub9 + "', "
                 + "[unit9] = '" + unit9 + "', "
                 + "[room9] = '" + room9 + "', "
                 + "[guro9] = '" + guro9 + "', "
                 + "[sec10] = '" + se10 + "', "
                 + "[sub10] = '" + sub10 + "', "
                 + "[unit10] = '" + unit10 + "', "
                 + "[room10] = '" + room10 + "', "
                 + "[guro10] = '" + guro10 + "' "
                 + "WHERE [studno] = '" + txtSearch->Text::get() + "'");
```

Can you determine what is a problem here?

Comment: Usually that error indicates a misspelled field name.

Comment: i checked all field name and no misspelled field name

Comment: Ok problem solved, 

i have a misspelled field name